# Extend Tibble by Row

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is the following: with mutate I can create new columns for instance as a combination of the existing ones, but what if I need to create new rows as combination of the existing ones?
For instance, consider

```
df<-structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), reporter = c("EU28", "EU28", "EU28", 
"EU28", "EU28", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"), partner = c("ACP", 
"ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP", "ACP"
), nace = c("FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI"), inward_stock = c(85483.9, 108674.6, 98536.9, 
114328.5, 174077.2, 4733.1, 5229.2, 5892.5, 7542.7, 20759), outward_stock = c(189229.3, 
223497.6, 325336.3, 301348.9, 304675.4, 38683, 46732.6, 49357.3, 
46985.6, 39748.4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I would like to add new rows for the years 2013-2017 where there is a new reporter EU27 and the values of the inward and outward stocks is the one of the EU28 without the UK contribution.

For instance, in 2013 the inward_stock for the EU27 would be 85484- 4733 = 80751 and the outward_stock 189229.-38683 = 150546.

Does anyone know how to achieve that without going through cumbersome pivoting/unpivoting? I would like to add 5 new rows in total

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case it would be fairly natural to use `summarize()` to create the data for EU27, and then bind that with the original data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

eu27 <- df %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-reporter, -ends_with("stock"))) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(inward_stock, outward_stock), ~ {
    .x[reporter == "EU28"] - .x[reporter == "UK"]
  }) %>% mutate(reporter = "EU27")

bind_rows(df, eu27)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>     year reporter partner nace  inward_stock outward_stock
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1  2013 EU28     ACP     FDI         85484.       189229.
#>  2  2014 EU28     ACP     FDI        108675.       223498.
#>  3  2015 EU28     ACP     FDI         98537.       325336.
#>  4  2016 EU28     ACP     FDI        114328.       301349.
#>  5  2017 EU28     ACP     FDI        174077.       304675.
#>  6  2013 UK       ACP     FDI          4733.        38683 
#>  7  2014 UK       ACP     FDI          5229.        46733.
#>  8  2015 UK       ACP     FDI          5892.        49357.
#>  9  2016 UK       ACP     FDI          7543.        46986.
#> 10  2017 UK       ACP     FDI         20759         39748.
#> 11  2013 EU27     ACP     FDI         80751.       150546.
#> 12  2014 EU27     ACP     FDI        103445.       176765 
#> 13  2015 EU27     ACP     FDI         92644.       275979 
#> 14  2016 EU27     ACP     FDI        106786.       254363.
#> 15  2017 EU27     ACP     FDI        153318.       264927
```

Here’s also a version with the cumbersome pivoting, using the new `pivot_*` functions in tidyr:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("stock"), names_to = "variable") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = reporter) %>%
  mutate(EU27 = EU28 - UK) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(EU28, UK, EU27), names_to = "reporter") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>     year partner nace  reporter inward_stock outward_stock
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1  2013 ACP     FDI   EU28           85484.       189229.
#>  2  2013 ACP     FDI   UK              4733.        38683 
#>  3  2013 ACP     FDI   EU27           80751.       150546.
#>  4  2014 ACP     FDI   EU28          108675.       223498.
#>  5  2014 ACP     FDI   UK              5229.        46733.
#>  6  2014 ACP     FDI   EU27          103445.       176765 
#>  7  2015 ACP     FDI   EU28           98537.       325336.
#>  8  2015 ACP     FDI   UK              5892.        49357.
#>  9  2015 ACP     FDI   EU27           92644.       275979 
#> 10  2016 ACP     FDI   EU28          114328.       301349.
#> 11  2016 ACP     FDI   UK              7543.        46986.
#> 12  2016 ACP     FDI   EU27          106786.       254363.
#> 13  2017 ACP     FDI   EU28          174077.       304675.
#> 14  2017 ACP     FDI   UK             20759         39748.
#> 15  2017 ACP     FDI   EU27          153318.       264927
```

I think the above reveals an interesting pattern that could be useful. A single pivoting function that could do both the “longer” and “wider” steps in one call, something along these lines:

```r
df %>%
  pivot(ends_with("stock"), names_to = "variable", names_from = reporter) %>%
  mutate(EU27 = EU28 - UK) %>%
  pivot(c(EU28, UK, EU27), names_to = "reporter", names_from = variable)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I believe this is OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure how dynamic you want this to be without doing pivoting, but a solution that is overfitted to your example can be,

```
new_reporter <- 'EU27'
l1 <- split(df, df$reporter)

rbind(df, data.frame(year = l1[[1]][1], 
                     reporter = new_reporter, 
                     partner = l1[[1]]$partner, 
                     nace = l1[[1]]$nace, 
                    l1[[1]][c(5:6)] - l1[[2]][c(5:6)]))

# A tibble: 15 x 6
#    year reporter partner nace  inward_stock outward_stock
#   <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1  2013 EU28     ACP     FDI         85484.       189229.
# 2  2014 EU28     ACP     FDI        108675.       223498.
# 3  2015 EU28     ACP     FDI         98537.       325336.
# 4  2016 EU28     ACP     FDI        114328.       301349.
# 5  2017 EU28     ACP     FDI        174077.       304675.
# 6  2013 UK       ACP     FDI          4733.        38683 
# 7  2014 UK       ACP     FDI          5229.        46733.
# 8  2015 UK       ACP     FDI          5892.        49357.
# 9  2016 UK       ACP     FDI          7543.        46986.
#10  2017 UK       ACP     FDI         20759         39748.
#11  2013 EU27     ACP     FDI         80751.       150546.
#12  2014 EU27     ACP     FDI        103445.       176765 
#13  2015 EU27     ACP     FDI         92644.       275979 
#14  2016 EU27     ACP     FDI        106786.       254363.
#15  2017 EU27     ACP     FDI        153318.       264927
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution, using `gather` and `spread` from `dplyr` :

```
df %>%
gather(type, stock, -c(year, reporter, partner, nace)) %>%
spread(reporter, stock) %>%
mutate(EU27=EU28-UK) %>%
gather(reporter, stock, -c(year, partner, nace, type)) %>%
spread(type, stock)
```

Output :

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
    year partner nace  reporter inward_stock outward_stock
   <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>
 1  2013 ACP     FDI   EU27           80751.       150546.
 2  2013 ACP     FDI   EU28           85484.       189229.
 3  2013 ACP     FDI   UK              4733.        38683 
 4  2014 ACP     FDI   EU27          103445.       176765 
 5  2014 ACP     FDI   EU28          108675.       223498.
 6  2014 ACP     FDI   UK              5229.        46733.
 7  2015 ACP     FDI   EU27           92644.       275979 
 8  2015 ACP     FDI   EU28           98537.       325336.
 9  2015 ACP     FDI   UK              5892.        49357.
10  2016 ACP     FDI   EU27          106786.       254363.
11  2016 ACP     FDI   EU28          114328.       301349.
12  2016 ACP     FDI   UK              7543.        46986.
13  2017 ACP     FDI   EU27          153318.       264927 
14  2017 ACP     FDI   EU28          174077.       304675.
15  2017 ACP     FDI   UK             20759         39748.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` package, we can solve the problem in the following way

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df), year, -reporter)
df[, .(reporter = "EU27", partner = "ACP", nace = "FDI", inward_stock = diff(inward_stock), outward_stock = diff(outward_stock)), year] %>% 
  rbind(df)
```

Another alternative

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, -"reporter"][, c(.(reporter = "EU27"), lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) -diff(x) else unique(x))), year] %>% 
  rbind(df)
```